# How to display a long id of 26 digits to short id of 8 digits in vuejs

Tags: html, vuejs2

I am facing issue in displaying a long ID `7e63c0d6-6310-4e52-ab8e-bb6f444f317e` to `7e63c0d6` in vuejs
can any one help on ow to display to 8 digits

Here is the code i have written to dislay the id:

```
 <span class="font-weight-bold">{{tutorial.id}}</span>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a method to cut the first digits up to the dash:

1. method:

```html
 <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ shortId(tutorial.id) }}</span>
```

```js
methods: {
  shortId(id) {
   const idx = id.indexOf('-')
   return id.slice(0, idx) // returns '7e63c0d6'
  }
}
```

2. inline method:

you can also do it in the template area, but only if you know that there are eight characters that you can shorten:

```html
 <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ tutorial.id.slice(0, 8) }}</span>
```